# Rails concerns not loading

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activesupport-concern

In my `application.rb` I have

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
      #{config.root}/lib/middleware 
      #{config.root}/lib 
      #{config.root}/lib/quickbooks/* 
      #{config.root}/lib/**/ 
      #{config.root}/app/models/concerns 
      #{config.root}/app/models/account)
```

and in `app/models/account` I have a file called `new_account_creation.rb` which has the contents:

```
module Account::NewAccountCreation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
  end
end
```

And lastly in my `account.rb` model file I have:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Account::NewAccountCreation
end
```

Whenever I run `bundle exec rake routes` I get this error below, as if the concern isn't loading.  I'm stuck, what's wrong?

```
rake aborted!
NameError: uninitialized constant Account::NewAccountCreation
/Users/Ackerman/src/Printavo/app/models/account.rb:57:in `<class:Account>'
/Users/Ackerman/src/Printavo/app/models/account.rb:56:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Ackerman/src/Printavo/lib/tasks/populate.rake:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Ackerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `block in load_tasks'
/Users/Ackerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `each'
/Users/Ackerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/engine.rb:425:in `load_tasks'
/Users/Ackerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:145:in `load_tasks'
/Users/Ackerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/Ackerman/src/Printavo/Rakefile:7:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Ackerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/Ackerman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Is populate.rake something you've added?

Comment: Ah, thank you so much @FrederickCheung! I had some weird `require`'s in there from a while ago.